# Calculate the Time Complexity for the code

Tags: algorithm

I have the below code which I am using for one of my application. I want to calculate the time complexity of this code.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j   = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
            {
                //TODO
            }
        }
```

I have tried calculating it below way:

```
: (n-1)(n-I-1)
: (n)(n-I-1) - (n-I-1)
: n^2-ni-n-n+i+1
: n^2-ni-2n+i+1
```

I don't know how to conclude this  . Though I see highest value of n is o(n^2).
Can anyone suggest what is the next step in determining the time complexity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code fragment is identical to this:

```
for m in n-1..0
    for j in 0..m
      i = n-1-m
      ...
```

which is the "classic" `O(N^2)`, except the outer loop goes from high to low rather than from low to high.

Comment: Thanks for reply.But,I want to know how does it evaluated to O(N^2) ?

Comment: @krrishna In the same way that `for i in 0..n for j in 0..i ...` does - as a sum of arithmetic sequence with the step of 1 (i.e. `n(n-1)/2`).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I think he is looking for why it is O(N^2)?

Comment: @Aravind But that's discussed in so many places, starting with wikipedia article on arithmetic sequences, that I didn't want to repeat this discussion again.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The next step is to drop the lower order terms from the polynomial: `-ni-2n+i+1` and you are left with `n^2`.

In general you would also drop any multiplicative constants attached to `n^2`. I. e. drop the `5` in `5*n^2` to get `n^2`

This follows from the definition of big-Oh which cares about whether one function dominates another as the input increases in size. As the input increases in size, the only term that matters is `n^2`. The lower order terms will not allow this function to dominate another function, and neither will any constants. So you just drop them.